# What is the standard Python module for SQL queries?

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am wondering what is the standard Python module for SQL queries?

I am writing queries for an Oracle database in particular. I am looking to write quick, easy, and direct queries, in the context of both scripts and small programs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each SQL database has their own module which implements [DB-API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). Oracle uses [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If, like me, you were trying to install this on Mac, I found the following link helpful: https://gist.github.com/tomstrummer/6011715

Answer (score 0):

DB-API is the standard API for accessing SQL databases from Python.

The following page provides further information: http://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming/

Comment: Is this preferable to SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @ktm5124: What?  "SQL queries" appears to mean "raw" SQL. SQLAlchemy doesn't do "raw" SQL.  It either rewrites SQL to be generic (in Python notation) or it uses an ORM, or both.  Please **update** your question to explain what you want to do.

Comment: S. Lott, you are quite condescending. I have 10 years of experience in Java, 5 in C, and only a few days' experience in Python. There is no need to write me off as an idiot when I am completely unfamiliar with Python.

Comment: And yes, I mean raw SQL queries. As in, passing a SQL query as a string parameter to a python function. Thank you for enlightening me on SQLAlchemy. It seems that it is not what I want after all.

Comment: @ktm5124: Don't take it personally, he's like that with everyone.